# How to make calendar icon using CSS

Tags: html, css, icons

How to make calendar design like this using CSS?
I tried using `after` & `transform` property but I'm unable to reach at this design.

Can this be achieved using css or should I use image background? What are the advantages and disadvantages of using CSS vs an image background?

If its possible using CSS please write the explanation also so that I can learn from it.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, your question was closed as not showing research in the future be more detailed and provide code that you tried and didn't work. 

You can check out this jsfiddle with a quick solution to your problem .  https://jsfiddle.net/4r1z25bw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with annotation.

Some resources

- [CSS positioning](https://youtu.be/P6UgYq3J3Qs)
- [Grid](https://youtu.be/rg7Fvvl3taU)
- [Custom properties](https://youtu.be/PHO6TBq_auI)

```css
body {
  /* Make the body the full height of the screen, otherwise it only takes up the height of the content */
  height: 100vh;

  /* put calendar in the centre of the screen using display: grid*/
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.tab {
  /* set up a css variable so that the left and right holes are the same distance from either edge */
  --tab-edge-distance: 120px;

  /* use this so that the holes, when positioned using position: absolute; are placed relative the this container */
  position: relative;
 
  background-color: #eaebed; 
  width: 500px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1; /* make it a square */
  border-radius: 2rem; /* make all borders curved */

  /*place the text in the centre using Grid */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.hole {
  /* this takes the hole outside the normal flow so we can use top, bottom, left, right, inset etc. to position it */
  position: absolute;
  
  background-color: white;
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
  
  /* place the hole 0 px from the top of the container. */
  top: 0;
}

.left {
  /* place the hole --tab-edge-distance px from the left of the container. */
  /* note we only have to definee this once so makes life easier */
  left: var(--tab-edge-distance);
}

.right {
  /* as above but right hand */
  right: var(--tab-edge-distance);
}

.number {
  /* should be self-explanatory */
  font-size: 12rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: #2a394e;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class='tab'>
  <div class='left hole'></div>
  <div class='right hole'></div>
  <div class='number'>01</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @Adam. Loved the simplicity of the solution

Comment: You're very welcome Noel.

Comment: If you want to sharpen up those CSS skills, have a look at cssbattle.dev

Comment: Thanks you very much for the recommendation. I will definitely go through it. Means a lot